# Can I hide <tr> if all elements in <tr> have display none class. After loading entire page

Tags: javascript

```
<form id="formid">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox">
          <input type="text" style="display:none">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" style="display:none">
          <input type="text" style="display:none">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox">
          <input type="text" style="display:none">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" style="display:none">
          <input type="text" style="display:none">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

I have multiple tables in a form, I want to hide all rows, where all elements have display none style. If we have only one element with display none style (but others are displayed) then no need to hide the row, in the above example hide second row of each table

Comment: `style="display="none"` is invalid

Comment: Yes, you can do this with javascript. What javascript have you tried to write so far? SO isn't a free coding service.

Comment: @sean I am using normal java script

Comment: Please edit your question to include the javascript you have written

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `display:none;` why don't you use `disabled` prop ?

In any case, you could do something like this by getting every `tr` and checking if its `input`s are disabled. If you really want to use `display:none` simply replace

`input.disabled` with `input.style.display === "none"`

If all the inputs are disabled within a `tr` the table row will be hidden.

- Use `addEventListener` to ensure the page has loaded before you run your javascript **OR** have your script at the end of your HTML page.
- `style="display=none"` is not correct. Use `style="display:none;"`

```js
window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
  Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("tr")).forEach(tr => {
  
      const shouldDisable = 
        Array.from(tr.querySelectorAll("input"))
        .every(input => input.disabled);
      
      if(shouldDisable){
          tr.style.display = "none"
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="formid">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox">
          <input type="text" style="display:none;">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox "  style="display:none;">
          <input type="text"  style="display:none;">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox"  style="display:none;">
          <input type="text"  style="display:none;">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox "  style="display:none;">
          <input type="text "  style="display:none;">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Nice answer, I would like to upload it, but for that purpose you need to do two things: 1. You will need to ensure that your code runs on page load, as the question asks us and 2. You should not set display to "block" if it happens to have at least one display input, because there might be a display value which would be overriden this way.

Comment: I tried using this input.style.display === "none" but it's not working for me. Sometimes i want to hide label and selectize after loading entire page, 
please help on that also

Comment: @Manil what do you mean by "Some times i want to hide label and selectize" and check my update regarding your previous problem.

Comment: @kemicofa
I created elements dynamically so any type of elements can be created
Eg:textbox,dropdown,label etc. Based on some condition we are adding display none class. If all the elements have display none class then need to hide that row

Comment: @Manil what you're trying to do is not very easy **unless** there are only direct children after the `td`. Otherwise, you'd need to come up with a *clear* plan on which elements may or may not have `dispaly:none;`... if you don't then you'd probably need to recursively check to see if every element within a TD has `dispaly:none;`

Comment: @kemicofa Thank for your support. In my form i have **n** number of tables and each table has **n**  number of TRs and TDs. Each TRs have different type of input elements Eg: Dropdown,label,input. So i need to check each tables and rows ,if all elements of a row have style `display:none` then **hide** that row.

Answer (score 0):

Let's define a `function` for this purpose

```
function hideRowIfNeeded() {
    var trs = document.querySelectorAll("#formid tr");
    for (var tr of trs) {
        var hide = true;
        var inputs = tr.querySelectorAll("input");
        for (var input of inputs) {
            if (input.style.display !== "none") hide = false;
        }
        if (hide) tr.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

And now you can specify `onload="hideRowIfNeeded()"` in your body tag.

Comment: Thank you I tried this. Its hiding all TRs which have at least one element without `display:none`. But i want hide TR only if all elements of that TR have style `display:none`
In my form i have n number of tables and each table has n number of TRs and TDs. Each TRs have different type of input elements Eg: Dropdown,label,input. So i need to check each tables and rows ,if all elements of a row have style display:none then hide that row

Comment: @Manil this code loads all trs in the form. For each tr, it loads all inputs and if any of them does not have a display none, then it hides it. Please add to this Fiddle the case which did not work for you and update it: https://jsfiddle.net/hznwtu0o/

Comment: Thank you for your support. Can you please check this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/1vxfsy2z/

Comment: @Manil you had some problems with the input selector, change it to var inputs = tr.querySelectorAll("input, select, label");. See: https://jsfiddle.net/zdg6qh15/